# could not get the kubernetes pod log info

Tags: kubernetes

After I renew the kubernetes v1.21 cluster certificate `kubeadm certs renew all` and open the kubernetes pods log in Lens, the console shows error:

```
Failed to load logs: Get "https://172.29.217.209:10250/containerLogs/reddwarf-pro/cv-render-service-7c4958fbbf-hhpn6/cv-render-service?tailLines=502&timestamps=true": dial tcp 172.29.217.209:10250: connect: connection refused
Reason: undefined (500)
```

the kubernetes pod running fine, and I have already tried to restart the kubelet service. why did this happen? what should I do to fixed this issue?

Answer (score 0):

same as your other question, you need to copy the new admin config `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` to your windows `%USERPROFILE%\.kube\config`

try renew all cert in all worker.

Comment: I have already copied the config and replaced. @yip102011 The lens can success fetch the pods list seems the config file worked, but could not get the pods log.

Comment: Seems like your kubelet isn't working properly. check the status of kubelet's service and logs and see if there're showing any issues.